# Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm creating a new angular service for components communication. but once I create my new Subject , I get this error : Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558). I'm working with Angular 7. this is My service :

```
import { Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from '../../../types/rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InteractionService {

  private sprintData = new Subject<any[]>();
  constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is your import statement. I'd change that to:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

I suspect that your current import is from internals.

Comment: Yes , that was it , I changed the import and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code, it would import eventEmitter from the protractor.
//import {EventEmitter} from'protractor'
instead, you would want to import this from 'angular/core'.